# Available Linux commands across Android versions

Tags: android, shell

I want to write some basic Linux commands in my Android app (namely ls, rm, cp, chmod with recursive -R option) but I am not sure whether they are available across different versions of the OS and whether they support "-R" or not. From my experience, cp seems to be added to Jelly Bean 4.2. The rest are all available in earlier versions.

May I ask if there is a source or reference for this? (Nothing seems to be available on the official Android site.)

Comment: Note also that the shells differ between versions as well.  `ash` on early versions, and `mksh` (which is much more powerful) from ICS (although it appears earlier on some devices).

Comment: Possible same on android SE: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-shell-commands Related: POSIX compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604455/is-android-posix-compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always fire up a avd and in adb shell run `ls /system/bin` and `ls /system/xbin`, it will show all the commands present.

Comment: Could it be the case that some device vendor choose NOT to ship some commands in their device?

Comment: yeah.. happens lots of times. If you check the emulator, tcpdump and some other things will be present, but production devices will not have these executables