# 'open' called with O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE, but missing mode

Tags: android, android-ndk, posix

On Linux I open a file with the following code:

```
auto file = ::open("file.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
```

but when I try to compile this code for Android (android-ndk-r26-beta2) I get the following compiler error:

```
error: 'open' called with O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE, but missing mode
```

what value should I pass to make it compile? Where is the documentation?

As far as I see it is [bionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604455/is-android-posix-compatible). What is its status?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
auto file = ::open("file.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

see https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/cpp/cpp-open-call-with-mode-argument/

Answer (score 1):

If you use `O_CREAT` variant, this is because you want the file to be created if non existing yet. Thus, in the case of creation it is requested that the file have permission bits set to some value (read, write, execute, etc). This is documented in man page of `open`:

> `O_CREAT`
>
> [...]
>
> The mode argument specifies the file mode bits to be
> applied when a new file is created.  If neither O_CREAT
> nor O_TMPFILE is specified in flags, then mode is ignored
> (and can thus be specified as 0, or simply omitted).  The
> mode argument must be supplied if O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE is
> specified in flags; if it is not supplied, some arbitrary
> bytes from the stack will be applied as the file mode.
>
> The effective mode is modified by the process's umask in
> the usual way: in the absence of a default ACL, the mode
> of the created file is (mode & ~umask).
>
> Note that mode applies only to future accesses of the
> newly created file; the open() call that creates a read-
> only file may well return a read/write file descriptor.
>
> The following symbolic constants are provided for mode:
>
> ```
>           S_IRWXU  00700 user (file owner) has read, write, and
>                    execute permission
>
>           S_IRUSR  00400 user has read permission
>
>           S_IWUSR  00200 user has write permission
>
>           S_IXUSR  00100 user has execute permission
>
>           S_IRWXG  00070 group has read, write, and execute
>                    permission
>
>           S_IRGRP  00040 group has read permission
>
>           S_IWGRP  00020 group has write permission
>
>           S_IXGRP  00010 group has execute permission
>
>           S_IRWXO  00007 others have read, write, and execute
>                    permission
>
>           S_IROTH  00004 others have read permission
>
>           S_IWOTH  00002 others have write permission
>
>           S_IXOTH  00001 others have execute permission
>
>           According to POSIX, the effect when other bits are set in
>           mode is unspecified.  On Linux, the following bits are
>           also honored in mode:
>
>           S_ISUID  0004000 set-user-ID bit
>
>           S_ISGID  0002000 set-group-ID bit (see inode(7)).
>
>           S_ISVTX  0001000 sticky bit (see inode(7)).
>
>           [...]
> ```

You have to make a call like:

```
auto file = ::open("file.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

or something like that.