# How to build Apache Portable Runtime to Android?

Tags: android, build, apr, cross-build

I know the APR doesn't have support on Android, but I really would like to use it.

For other libraries i followed this [NDK guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems). But APR has a more complex `./configure` script which checks more things.

I'm sure that modifying something is needed. But I'm not as much experienced on this library to know where to start.

I've tried to build-it setting parameters before the `configure` script. I've managed to run thought 80% of the script, but modifying some variables (looking at `config.log`):

```
ac_cv_file__dev_zero=yes
ac_cv_func_getpgrp_void=no
ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void=yes
ac_cv_func_memcmp_working=yes
rb_cv_binary_elf=no 
rb_cv_negative_time_t=no
ac_rc=no
pr_cv_mutex_robust_shared=no
apr_cv_tcp_nodelay_with_crok=yes
```

Modify more variables like this and let's run more "tests" of the script. But are thease variables rellevant? Will this cause some trouble when using the libary? Is this the right way to build it to Andoird or I shuld do something else?

Thanks!

Comment: More of a FYI, as [Android isn't full Linux POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27604455/295004), you can use pseudo Linux environment like [Termux](https://termux.dev/en/) as it appears that Termux does support [Apache Portable Runtime](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/blob/master/packages/apr/build.sh)

Comment: I've read about it. I suppose the Termux needs to be installed alongside my app. I wonder if any _linux subsystem_ for android apps exists.

Answer (score 0):

I also managed to build apr-1.7.4 in android NDK with the options

```
ac_cv_file__dev_zero=yes ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void=yes apr_cv_process_shared_works=yes apr_cv_mutex_robust_shared=yes apr_cv_tcp_nodelay_with_cork=yes
```

to ./configure.
I don't see any problems with the application depending on apr-1 yet.