# Porting of Linux library to Android

Tags: android, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I have a rather complex project that needs to be ported to android. Parts of it use libraries such as Apache Runtime Library. I tried my luck with the cross-compiler, but the configuration step throws all kinds of wild errors. I think APR is pretty low level, so I am not exactly sure it is possible to cross-compile it at all.

Now my solutions are either:

- Get my hands dirty and try to make the cross-compiling work
- Rewrite parts of the software so APR is not needed

Both tasks are not exactly sparking joy inside of me, hence my question: Is there a third way? Maybe some kind of virtual Linux machine to run on Android?

Note: It should be deployable via AppStore.

Thanks for the info!

Comment: There are comments under this question that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044918/how-to-build-apache-portable-runtime-to-android